# The kind of jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen jQuery code's like this

```
 return 13 == t.keyCode ? (t.preventDefault(), !1) : void 0
```

What that mean for `?` and `:` ?

Please give me reference, because I still newbie in jQuery. Thank's a lot

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: its shorthand style of writing if else

Comment: This is not jQuery. It's JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Be sure to know the difference between jQuery and Javascript. Javascript is what the browser understands. jQuery is written in Javascript, and is "just" a library to make a lot of commonly used design patterns in web design easier. Try to understand the basics of Javascript before dabbling in jQuery, otherwise you might run into more problems like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its ternary operator.
Shorthand for writting if/else

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: this is more of a comment other answer deserves the upvote

Answer (score 2):

It is a shorthand for if else:

**Translation:**

```
if(13 == t.keyCode) { return (t.preventDefault(), !1); } else { return void 0; }
```

Comment: it should be if(13 == t.keyCode)

Comment: correct my bad.